# Update phone to 12.2 and now xcode 10 is throwing error when building app

Tags: xcode10, ios12

I have update an iphone X to use the lates ios release 12.2

Now when I try to Run my app on with xcode 10.1 I got the following error:

```
This iPhone X (Model A1865, A1901, A1902, A1903) is running iOS 12.2 
(16E5191d), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.
```

Also the web inspector on safari seems to be busted on the same phone...

Anyone else is experiencing this issue?

Comment: Download the latest version of xcode try XCode 10.2 beta.

Comment: yes that should do the trick.. but we had some other issue with XCode beta version.. might hold on and wait for a more stable release.. just park the phone for a little bit

Comment: you can do one thing just create generic build and open device and simulator window drag and drop app in your device. But its only help to run app in your device you can not debug with Xcode

Comment: I think they fixed everything with the new ios release.. bit messy but got there at the end